# Is dropping a bromine tab in my sump pit bad?

Tags: sump-pump

I have a sump pump that runs a lot (I have a perched water table under my house).

It discharges into my gutter and there is a significant mold build up.

My sump pit is just a hole in the ground, but I would like to try dropping a bromine tab in my sump pit.

My worry is that this will mess up the ground water.

My second worry is that it will mess up my pump.

Are these valid concerns or can I just try this out and see if it helps my mold issues?

Answer (score 1):

It won't mess up your pump, there's much heavier minerals in the water than bromine. However, you have to be weary of where the water is discharged. Bromine isn't going to be healthy for your lawn or nearby trees. It's probably best to spot-treat the mold with bleach and maybe mold-resistant epoxy paint. If you use bromine, re-route your discharge into the sewer.

Comment: It can very easily mess up your pump. Bromine can be corrosive and attack the components of your sump pump. As evidence, all I can offer are the remains of the sump pump we had to replace a short time after this was essentially done to us.

Comment: Heavy minerals would certainly not be an issue because Bromine has additives to keep it in a solid "tab" state anyhow before it dissociates. Bromine is one of only two elements liquid at room temperature (the other being Hg).

Comment: By the way, be careful about sending sump pump effluent into a municipal sewer system. Surprisingly, this MAY be against the rules in your area, gaining you a hefty fine if caught.

Comment: Temporarily redirecting the treated water won't be a problem.  Permanently redirecting is a no-no.